# Вызов методов dataSource в UIColletionView при изменении высоты

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

У меня есть `UIColletionView` у которой высота завязана на `Constraint`, может кто-нибудь объяснить, почему если у меня высота `UIColletionView` была 0 а стала например 100, вызывается обновление `UIColletionView` и запрашиваются данные у dataSource ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У вас появился видимый контент, который нужно отобразить.
Поэтому он и запрашивает данные, которые ему отображать.

Comment: Благодарю вас за ответ, возможно ли это как-то перевести на ручное управление?

Comment: @ВикторМишустин что по вашему тогда должно отображаться, когда UICollectionView стал больше?
Можете описать, чего именно вы хотите достичь?

Comment: Разобрался во всем, спасибо!